# Windows 10 dual boots straight to Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

The only way I can get back into Windows 10 is to go into the boot manager where it shows these items and choosing the second option with the first being the newly-installed Ubuntu installation:

1. Windows Boot Manager (Intel OEMRAID0)
2. Windows Boot Manager (Intel OEMRAID0)
3. Linux (OEMRAID0)

The third one appeared after I tried boot repair in Ubuntu.

If I select the first one, a blank Grub Loader screen appears and then boots straight into Ubuntu 18.04.

I have 2 x 128 gb for Windows and 1 x 1 TB that has about 260 gb for Ubuntu with the rest for data and storage for Windows.

Both OSes should be installed under UEFI, but if there's a sure way to check, I'm glad to do it, and os-prober returns nothing.

This is what fdisk shows: (excluding loop devices)

```
Disk /dev/sda: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe0d5da1e

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           1 4294967295 4294967295   2T ee GPT

Disk /dev/sdb: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdc: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 69F57C74-1B25-417A-94DA-8FA89C8F8BF8

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1          34      32767      32734    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdc2       32768 1433632767 1433600000 683.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdc3  1433632768 1953523711  519890944 247.9G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/md126: 238.5 GiB, 256066453504 bytes, 500129792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6B279885-C27E-4714-8AF9-B8CC095E89B9

Device           Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/md126p1      2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/md126p2    206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/md126p3    239616 498014207 497774592 237.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/md126p4 498014208 500111359   2097152     1G Windows recovery environment
```

Comment: Can you give us more information? Is Windows installed in UEFI mode and Ubuntu in Legacy BIOS mode or the other way around? Are they both in the same SSD/HDD? How did you install Ubuntu with OEM RAID0?

Comment: Edited question with more details.

Comment: In make sure that only UEFI is enabled. In boot sequence you can see all options for you to boot. Scheck whether both OSs are there.

Comment: Yes, I can definitely boot into both OSes, but GRUB loader just won't show anything. I have UEFI enabled, but Secure Boot disabled.